# Getting "Msstdfmt.dll missing" when starting Visual Basic 6 application

Tags: windows-7, visual-basic

I need to run an old application written in Visual Basic 6 under Windows 7 x64. When I open it I obtain a message complaining that the library `msstdfmt.dll`cannot be found.

I've tried to install the latest VB 6 runtime available [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24417) but I still get the error.

How can I overcome this error message? I'd like to obtain the missing dll from a reliable and possibly durable source.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've resolved this problem using the procedure described in this [blog post](https://scivision.co/windows-xp-missing-class-msstdfmt-dll/), in which the DLL is extracted from a tool built and distributed by Microsoft.

For the sake of convenience, I repeat the procedure here:

1. download from Microsoft [this tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12972) for Exchange 2000, that incidentally is a VB6 program redistributed with `msstdfmt.dll`
2. run the program, extracting its contents to a folder of your choice
3. copy `msstdfmt.dll` to `c:\windows\system32` if running on 32 bit OS or to `c:\windows\syswow64` if running on a 64 bit OS
4. open a command prompt (`cmd.exe`) with administrator privileges
5. in the prompt type on 32 bit OS

   ```
   regsvr32 c:\windows\system32\msstdfmt.dll
   ```

   or on 64 bit OS

   ```
   regsvr32 c:\windows\syswow64\msstdfmt.dll
   ```
6. now your VB6 program should start successfully

Comment: Microsoft removed the liked page, but the library is available here http://www.dlldump.com/download-dll-files_new.php/dllfiles/M/MSSTDFMT.DLL/6.00.84506/download.html

Comment: I was able to find it in a Microsoft product, VB6 service pack 6 - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9183